# Building openocd on linux for windows requires which winusb drivers

Tags: fedora-25, openocd

I need to build openocd for windows. I tried building openocd on linux for 64-bit windows by using spec file. Build succeeded but when I tried to use the generated openocd.exe on windows, it gives me the error

> “LIBUSB_ERROR_NOT_FOUND”.

On windows, although I have WINUSB drivers which I am using to program MCU, I am still getting same error. 
Can anybody help, Does anybody also face the same issue?

Although if I am building openocd through cygwin on windows machine, openocd works properly.

My requirement is to build on linux machine only.

PS: I am using fedora fc25 linux machine

Comment: You might try Zadig: http://zadig.akeo.ie/ It can create a USB driver for Windows on-the-fly for accessing libusb/winusb devices.

Comment: Hi, I tried zadig. Still I am getting the same error.